# How to write an if statements which test number sequence:

Tags: numbers, sequence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYRMK.png)

I'm writing a small code which can help in placing the wells at 3 different configurations (producers/Yellow and injectors/blue), as shown in the schematic attached i.e.:
for the 1st configuration (Producer follow by Injector), it is pretty straightforward:-
if number % 2==1 (odd) then producer else if it even then it's an injector.

How to do that for configurations 2 & 3 ? producer producer injector (PPI) and producer injector producer (PIP)?

thanks a lot in advance,

```
                    for j in range(0,7*int(well_spacing/10),int(well_spacing/10)):
                           if well_config=='PIP':
                               if (number % 2 == 1): # odd number top of 1A
                                   if (prod_loc=='top1a'):
                                       k= 2 # producers in layer 2
                                   else: # (number % 2 == 1) and prod_loc=='mid1a': # odd number mid of 1A
                                       k= 4 # producers in layer 4
                               else:
                                   if (number % 2 != 1):  # even number
                                       if (inj_loc=='top1b'):
                                           k= 8  # inj in layer 4
                                       else: # (number % 2 != 1) and inj_loc=='belowowc': even number belowowc
                                           k= 18 # inj in layer 18
                           elif  well_config=='PPI':
                               if (number % 2 == 1):# odd number top of 1A
                                   if (prod_loc=='top1a'):
                                       k= 2 # producers in layer 2
                                   else:  # (number % 2 == 1) and prod_loc=='mid1a': # odd number mid of 1A  
                                       k= 4 # producers in layer 4
                               else:
                                   if (number % 2 != 1): 
                                       if (inj_loc=='top1b'):
                                           k= 8  # inj in layer 4
                                       else: # (number % 2 != 1) and inj_loc=='belowowc': even number belowowc
                                           k= 18 # inj in layer 18
                           elif  well_config=='PIP':
                                  if (number % 2 == 1): # odd number top of 1A
                                     if (prod_loc=='top1a'):   
                                          k= 2 # producers in layer 2
                                     else: # (number % 2 == 1) and prod_loc=='mid1a': # odd number mid of 1A
                                          k= 4 # producers in layer 4
                                  else:
                                       if (number % 2 != 1):
                                          if (inj_loc=='top1b'):
                                              k= 8  # inj in layer 4
                                          else: # (number % 2 != 1) and inj_loc=='belowowc': even number belowowc
                                              k= 18 # inj in layer 18                                
                           number += 1
                           i = int(well_spacing/10/2)
                           well_locations.append((i,j,k,int(well_length/10))
```